# procedure doesn't work for evey pattern in prolog

Tags: prolog, counter

I try to find how many children a person have. Created my sample space and in find procedure I should count the numbers of children and print the value.

Sample input/output:

```
?- find(joe,Result).
false.
```

I tried to change `find(X,R)` like that:

```
find(X,R) :-
   R is 0 .
   R is R+1 ,    
   father(X,Y).
   write(R).
```

Then its input/output became like that

```
?- find(joe,R).
R = 0.
```

I tried what i know about prolog but i think i have few knowledge to do that task. All suggestions are welcome. Thanks for all your interest.

```
:- [library(clpr)].

mother(susan, sue).
father(joe, eric).
father(joe, smith).
father(joe, barrack).
father(sue, john).
father(eric, bill).
father(bill, george).

find(X,R):-
   R is 0,
   R is R+1 ,
   father(X,Y).
```

Comment: Prolog is a *declarative* language: it means that once you've set a variable (`R`) you cannot set it to a different value.

Comment: Note that you have mistyped a period `.` where a comma `,` belongs in your second code block, between `R = 0` and `R = R+1`.  As CommuSoft points out, the latter statement will not do anything useful, or at least will not do what you hoped here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the number of all children of a specific person, you need to collect all solutions to `father(Father, Children)` or `mother(Mother, Children)` and count them. For example:

```
number_of_childrens(Person, N) :-
    findall(Children, (father(Person, Children); mother(Person, Children)), Childrens),
    length(Childrens, N).
```

For example:

```
?- number_of_childrens(joe, N).
N = 3.
```

Comment: I did not understand why it worked. Is finall and length are declared procedure in prolog basic library? I try to implement number_of_childerens procedure to my other prolog code but it didn't worked. Does your code only works on static procedure? Because the implemented procedure was dynamic. It works same. Only changed place is fact base.

Comment: Both the `findall/3` and the `length/2` predicates are built-in predicates in  most Prolog implementations, including the one you used to tag your question. The code and the sample result used the knowledge base of `father/2` and `mother/2` facts in your question. It doesn't matter if these predicates are dynamic or static.

Comment: At least some `sort/2` would eliminate redundant answers and the dependence on the particular order.

Comment: @false The question text and examples show the predicate called with the person (for which we want to know the number of children) **bound**. My answer assumes that no person in the database is, at the same time, a father and a mother, and there are do duplicated facts. If that's not the case, or if the first argument can be unbound, `setof/3` could be used instead of `findall/3` to avoid those issues.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot easily replace `findall/3` by `setof/3` for all those without children. In any case, such implicit assumptions as you now state them in this comment need to be made explicit.

Comment: @false Assumptions that no one is both a father and a mother and that the KB have no duplicated facts are more than reasonable for the question itself and don't belong in answers.